# What is the third byte of a hex number? Scope: reading an API

Tags: c++, binary, hex

I have a DLL which manage reporting for a printer. DLL has a function which returns an HEX error code for the printer status.

In my case the function return this HEX number

```
   0x0000 - 0x0405
```

[image]

I do not understand what is the 3rd Byte and retrieve the error.

Could you please point me out in the right direction and tell me what is the 3 Byte in my ex and at which error correspond from the table?

Comment: big endian or little endian?

Comment: @MitchWheat does that matter? I'd think you'd `&` with `1<<n` either way

Comment: sorry i am not sure about edian but i hitnk it is little endian. what I can tell that 0x0000 - 0x0004 = Paper present

Comment: "tell me what is the 3 Byte in my ex" :-D

Comment: Please revise your question's title; it's missing the most important bit: the scope, i.e. that it's about a particular API.

Comment: Title modified, I hope it make more sense now... thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read it as binary: 0x04 = 0000-0100 and 0x05 = 0000-0101

According to the table the first code is "near paper end" and the second is "near paper end" and "paper not present". Said in this way it looks like a nonsense, but you can easily interpret a "no more paper" inclusive of "low paper".